# How the Barebox boots up for Beaglebone Black?

Tags: bootloader

I want to know the step-by-step boot sequence of Barebox for Beaglebone Black.
which function will execute first to how it handover the control to Kernel?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to check this [presentation](https://elinux.org/images/9/9d/Barebox-bells-n-whistles.pdf) first. Page 3 and 4 are showing boot sequence in picture.

If you want to get barebox binary for Beaglebone board, you will enable 'CONFIG_MACH_BEAGLEBONE'.

In file 'images/Makefile.am33xx' you find entry function named 'start_am33xx_beaglebone_sdram' for this config option (SDRAM)

```
pblx-$(CONFIG_MACH_BEAGLEBONE) += start_am33xx_beaglebone_sdram
FILE_barebox-am33xx-beaglebone.img = start_am33xx_beaglebone_sdram.pblx
am33xx-barebox-$(CONFIG_MACH_BEAGLEBONE) += barebox-am33xx-beaglebone.img
```

This entry function is the "first step" (low level HW init) defined in 'arch/arm/boards/beaglebone/lowlevel.c' file.

Then the call chain is like 'barebox_arm_entry' ('arch/arm/include/asm/barebox-arm.h') -> 'barebox_*_pbl_start' ('arch/arm/cpu/entry.c') -> ...

Then [initcalls](https://github.com/saschahauer/barebox/blob/f9e320b6fee489a5634aca59fe5715e208353621/README#L61) will be called

```
#define core_initcall(fn)       __define_initcall("1",fn,1)
#define postcore_initcall(fn)       __define_initcall("2",fn,2)
#define console_initcall(fn)        __define_initcall("3",fn,3)
#define postconsole_initcall(fn)    __define_initcall("4",fn,4)
#define mem_initcall(fn)        __define_initcall("5",fn,5)
#define mmu_initcall(fn)        __define_initcall("6",fn,6)
#define postmmu_initcall(fn)        __define_initcall("7",fn,7)
#define coredevice_initcall(fn)     __define_initcall("8",fn,8)
#define fs_initcall(fn)         __define_initcall("9",fn,9)
#define device_initcall(fn)     __define_initcall("10",fn,10)
#define crypto_initcall(fn)     __define_initcall("11",fn,11)
#define of_populate_initcall(fn)    __define_initcall("12",fn,12)
#define late_initcall(fn)       __define_initcall("13",fn,13)
#define environment_initcall(fn)    __define_initcall("14",fn,14)
#define postenvironment_initcall(fn)    __define_initcall("15",fn,15)
```

See [these definitions](https://github.com/saschahauer/barebox/blob/f9e320b6fee489a5634aca59fe5715e208353621/include/init.h#L56).

Last (environment) init calls will load environment and run 'init' script(s). With boot/bootm/.. barebox commands you can load 'zImage', 'dtb', 'initrd' and pass commandline arguments for Linux kernel.